# Discord.js on Heroku cannot find module

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I am running discord.js on Heroku. I wrote a module, but in the logs says "Error: Cannot find module '.\modules**.js'".

The code itself:

```
const { MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const demotivator = require('C:\\app\\modules\\demotivator.js')
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
        config: {
                name: `demo`,
                aliases: [`demo`]
        }
```

Comment: `require('C:\\app\\modules\\demotivator.js')`?? On Heroku?

Comment: Zsolt Meszaros, I don't know how to write the right directory on Heroku

Comment: You should look into (i.e. google) relative paths in Node.js. The answer depends on where this file is. It can be `require('./demotivator.js')`, `require('../demotivator.js')`, `require('./module/demotivator.js')`, etc. It depends where you're requiring `demotivator.js` from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use heroku but heroku certainly doesn't have a C drive. I'm assuming you have copied and pasted this code from your computer. Correct me if I'm wrong but you would need to find the path of demotivator.js and then paste it in the const statement. If the demotivator is in the same directory then it would be

```
const demotivator=require('./demotivator.js')
```

if it is in a folder in that same directory it would be

```
const demotivator=require('./<foldername>/demotivator.js')
```

If demotivator is behind the current directory it would be

```
const demotivator=require('../demotivator.js')
```

if it it 2 directories behind you can do

```
const demotivator=require('../../demotivator.js')
```

you can keep doing `../../` if you were wondering

Comment: Couple of things to fix: `<filename>` should be probably folder, in `demotivator-require` the `-` should be `=`.